# SQL: How to select rows with a column value that appears at least 1 times?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database like the following.

[image: Database Example]
I want to get the account number and money of the accounts that have at least one
holder (ID Card) of both sexes, that is, at least one male holder and at least one female holder.

This should be the result:

[image: Result]

This is the query I am using but it returns 0 rows. What could be the problem?

```
select accountNumber, money
from mytable
group by accountNumber, money
having min(sex) <> max(sex)
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select accountNumber, money
from mytable
group by accountNumber, money
having min(sex) <> max(sex)
```

Condition `min(sex) <> max(sex)` is a simple and efficient way to ensure that both possible values are available for the given `(accountNumber, money)` tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select accountNumber, sum(money)
from t
group by accountNumber
having sum(sex = 'M') >= 1 and sum(sex = 'F') >= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `count`.

```
select
    accountNumber,
    Money
from yourTable
group by
    accountNumber,
    Money
having count(distinct sex) > 1
```